# How to prevent individual form elements from updating using Meteor + React?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I have a Meteor + React single-page-application with a basic form in it. Data is collected from MongoDB using the `createContainer` method and passed to a form component. The problem I am facing is this. A user starts completing the form but, if the data that originally populated the form changes (by another user somewhere else in the world saving the form), the `createContainer` method will re-compute, which in turn pushes a new set of `props` to the form component and therefore overwrites what the user is typing in.
For many reasons, I cannot use the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method within the form component. One reason is that the form contains a `select` element, whose list of items should still accept reactive updates.
I need a way of halting certain reactive updates, but allowing others, whilst the user is completing the form. Any suggestions?

```
export default FormContainer = createContainer(( params ) => {

    const dataFormHandle = Meteor.subscribe('FormsPub');
    const dataFormIsReady = dataFormHandle.ready();
    const dataListHandle = Meteor.subscribe('ListItemsPub');
    const dataListIsReady = dataListHandle.ready();

    let name = "";
    let listItems = [];
    let listSelectedValue = null;

    if(dataListIsReady) {
        listItems = collections.ListItemsColl.find({_id: ListId}).fetch();
    }

    if(dataFormIsReady) {
        let formData = collections.FormsColl.find({_id: formId}).fetch();
        name = formData[0].name;
        listSelectedValue = formData[0].listSelectedValue;
    }

    return {
        name,
        listItems,
        listSelectedValue
    };
}, Form);
```

...

```
export default class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: (this.props.name) ? this.props.name : "",
            listSelectedValue: (this.props.listSelectedValue) ? this.props.listSelectedValue : null
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({name: (nextProps.name) ? nextProps.name : ""});
        this.setState({listSelectedValue: (nextProps.listSelectedValue) ?  nextProps.listSelectedValue : null});
    }

    updateFormState(){
        var name = e.target.name;
        var val = e.target.value;
        if(name == "name"){this.setState({name: val});}
        if(name == "list"){
            if( typeof e.target[e.target.selectedIndex] != "undefined" ) {
                this.setState({listSelectedValue: val});
            }
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.updateFormState.bind(this)} />
                <Select2
                    value={this.state.listSelectedValue}
                    name="list"
                    onChange={this.updateFormState.bind(this)}
                    options={{
                        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
                    }}
                    data={this.props.listItems}
                />
            </div>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could use an state named `isTyping` in your `Form` component. Set that state to true when user is typing, and when it is true you can simply ignore the new `name` value in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: It's not just when they are typing, it's when they are using the page with the form on it. So I could use this principle where I set `isTyping` when the data has loaded, but how to check for this?

Answer (score 1):

For the data in the form that you wish to be *non-reactive* simply specify `reactive: false` in your `.find()`, for example:

```
let formData = collections.FormsColl.find({ _id: formId },{ reactive: false }).fetch();
```

This will prevent the data from reactively updating while the form is open.

Comment: I don't think that this will work because createContainer will still send props to the component and force an update.

Comment: Then you might have to put the reactive select menu in a separate component, that way an update to it doesn't also update the rest of the form.